# How to set Page.IsValid in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, validation

When the page class property `IsValid` is read only, how can I set it using my own validation method?

So far all I've been able to do is set this property by calling `Page.Validate()`.

How can I write my own functionality that will change the `IsValid` property just like `Page.Validate()`?

Answer (score 11):

You don't set **IsValid** directly instead you call **Validate()** method of the **Page** object. If you have your custom validation methods then you need to use **CustomValidator** object and set that function in its server side validation property.

```
  <asp:CustomValidator ID="YourValidator" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true"  
      ControlToValidate="YourControl"
        ClientValidationFunction="YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION" 
        OnServerValidate="YOUR_SERVER_VALIDATION_FUNCTION" Text="*" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but, I needed to do something similar, basically forcing the IsValid property to false (don't ask why). Here is what I did basically (what you see here is my proof of concept):

Added this to the .aspx page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDummy" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rvDummy" ControlToValidate="txtDummy" runat="server" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="2" />
```

And then I added this to the code behind:

```
bool makeMyPageInvalid = true;
if (makeMyPageInvalid)
    txtDummy.Text = "0";

Page.Validate();

if (Page.IsValid)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "test", "alert('valid');", true);
else
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "test", "alert('not valid');", true);
```

You can see that this only allows you to force the page validation to an invalid state. You can use any validator or reason to set this. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

The `IsValid` property is read-only because it is intended for use with server and client-side validators like the `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator`.  It's read-only because you can't force a page to be valid programmatically. "Valid" in this context means all the validators on the page evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like using some JavaScript you can do it in the client-side by modifying the variable `Page_IsValid` like this:

```
function pageLoad() {
    Page_IsValid = false;
}
```

I use this just in case someone clicks the submit button w/o entering data. Then I can display an alert like this:

```
function valid() {
    if (!Page_IsValid) {
        alert("Some Questions Remain Unanswered and are Marked with a Red Asterisc. ( * )");
    }
```

(at the beginning I thought 'who would submit a form w/o data' but sooner rather than later I realized it happens)

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old question, but it came up in a search so I thought I'd add my answer to it. First, create an extension method in one of your helper classes.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllControlsOfType<T>(this Control parent) where T : Control
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (control is T)
        {
            result.Add((T)control);
        }
        if (control.HasControls())
        {
            result.AddRange(control.GetAllControlsOfType<T>());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now in your code behind file, loop over every validator on the page that is not validating.

```
foreach (var validator in Page.GetAllControlsOfType<BaseValidator>().Where(w => !w.IsValid))
{
    validator.IsValid = true;
}
```