# Required Field validator is not working, server click event is fired before client side validation

Tags: vb.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have required field validator inside grid

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtfirstname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName")%>' ValidationGroup="ValidateSender" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqedFieldValtorFirstName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtfirstname" ErrorMessage="Input is mandatory" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="ValidateSender"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

I also have a button to fire the error as

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Visible="false" ToolTip="Save" Text="Save" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ValidateSender" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
```

My server side button click is

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Try
            Page.Validate()
            If Page.IsValid Then
                Dim SendersList As CommonFramework.BaseList(Of NotificationSendersBO) = New CommonFramework.BaseList(Of NotificationSendersBO)()

                SendersList = FindControlRecursiveAndGetBOs()

                m_senderPresenter.SaveSenderDetails(SendersList)

                m_senderPresenter.GetSenderDetails()

                btnReset.Visible = False
                btnSave.Visible = False
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            LogException.Publish(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

But always the server side click is firing and on client side required field validator is not working.

Update : ihave done debugging and it is fired after server side click event was executed , which is not what is expected .

Let me know how I can solve this issue.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Already checked out [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1025315/9290012)

Comment: Thanks for your comment , This has solved my issue , But I am still not understanding why it is going to server first to validate , why is it not validate only on client side ?